# How to get XPath from a JAXB annotated class at compile time without an instance of the class?

Tags: java, xpath, jaxb

I have a JAXB annotated class:

```java
package com.stackexchange.question;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.*;

import lombok.experimental.FieldNameConstants;
import lombok.Data;

import org.eclipse.persistance.oxm.annotations.XmlCDATA;

@Data
@FieldNameConstants
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Sample {
    @XmlCDATA
    @XmlElement(name = "fall", nillable = true)
    private String fall;

    @XmlElement(name = "number")
    private Number number;
}

@Data
@FieldNameConstants
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Number {
    @XmlCDATA
    @XmlElement(name = "classroom", nillable = true)
    private String classroom;
}
```

I need a way to generate the XPath at compile-time. For example, I want a way to go about it in a type-safe manner. Currently, I'm encapsulating all of the field classes within the parent class so I can do `Sample.Number.class` + `Sample.Fields.number` and then looping through using `getEnclosingClass` before using the annotations to get the names, and finally generate the XPath through that.

Is there a better way to do it? I already have all the JAXB annotated classes, so I essentially have a skeleton of the XML through the class, but I can't generate the XPath without a hacky way of doing it.

I don't mind using a library if it provides this feature.